# Prefer text/plain attachment to text/html attachment in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, plaintext

Is there a way to have Thunderbird prefer the text/plain attachment to a text/html attachment when both are available in a message?

Here's my problem:

I want to view the output of my cron jobs as plain text. I have Thunderbird configured to use a monospace font for plain text emails. However, somebody (I suspect my Exchange server) is adding a text/html attachment to the message. When Thunderbird sees that it renders the text/html attachment in a proportional font. I'd like Thunderbird to only see the text/plain attachment and render it using monospaced font.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Go to the file menu:

> View > Message Body As > Plain Text

This will default all incoming emails to display the plain-text version.

To change this back:

> View > Message Body As > Original HTML

Comment: Another good option is to select `Simple HTML`. This often provides clearer view than `Original HTML`, yet without the oversimplification of `Plain Text`