# Thunderbird disable remote content warning for HTML email

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

In Thunderbird version 12.01, is there a way to disable the remote content warning that appears in situations such as: when an HTML email wants to load images hosted online?

I expected that the Security tab in Preferences would have an two options: Don't load remote content and Don't warn when an email requests remote content. 
Not finding this, I went to about:config (config editor) looking for the options. I found

> mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image => true

but settings this to **false** automatically loads the remote content, which is not the intended outcome.

Is there a way to suppress the prompt to "Show Remote Content" without loading the remote content?

(just as an addendum, I don't want to add contacts to my contact list)

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04 if anyone is interested

Comment: Unbelievable this option is unavailable in TB for so many years!

Answer (score 2):

[There is a hidden switch for this](https://bugzilla-dev.allizom.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608844#c3):

In `about:config` (Preferences -> Advanced -> Config Editor) look for:

```
permissions.default.image
```

change from `1` to `2`.

Comment: Thunderbird version 31 once again has broken the setting, so now this trick is obsolete...

Comment: Yet another solution is to select `Simple HTML` in the `View message as` menu. https://superuser.com/a/173612/175541

Comment: No, it does work. Thunderbird 38.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.11. No remote content. No yellow stripe. So much better....

Answer (score 0):

You won't get that warning if you use the [Allow HTML Temp](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/allow-html-temp/) add-on and set it to view emails in Simple HTML or Plain Text.